# How to handle exceptions with builders

Tags: java

I have a builder for a class with the following method which uses the Google libphonenumber library.

```
public final Builder withPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, String region)
            throws NumberParseException,IllegalArgumentException {

    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

    if (!phoneUtil.getSupportedRegions().contains(region)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Region code is invalid.");
    }

    PhoneNumber inputNumber = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber, region);
    String formattedNumber = phoneUtil.format(inputNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.E164);

    this.phoneNumbers.add(formatterNumber);

    return this;
}
```

The method needs to check that the `phoneNumber` argument is a valid form and that the `region` argument is one of the allowable regions. Normally if this was just a mutator method for the class not the builder I'd just handle the exceptions internally and return `false` if one occurs, but since I'm limited to returning the `Builder` type I cannot return a `boolean`. Would it be better to propagate the exception to the user as I have done above (requiring the user to surround their builder call with try catch blocks) or should I just manage the exceptions internally by returning the unchanged builder (i.e. rejecting the new phone number if it's invalid)? My only concern with the second option is that the user is not notified why the method call isn't adding the phone number to the builder, but I suppose I could just put that in javadoc.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet that you posted seems the right approach to me. I don't think you have any reason to be worried because:

1. The `IllegalArgumentException` is *not* a checked exception, so you're not forcing clients to surround the building code in `try`/`catch` blocks.
2. The input is usually supposed to be validated *before* you start building your domain objects. The validation logic should guard the UI input and not allow any transaction to begin until the input data is valid.

The second bullet means that inside your builder you just perform a double-check, and not the actual validation which results in error messages in the UI.

You can think about it this way: what if the input was `null` (for either `phoneNumber` or `region`). Most likely, that will result in a `NullPointerException`, which is the correct behavior. And you don't expect clients to `catch` the NPE; they're just not supposed to call your method with that kind of input.